# How to convert a child.jsp as modal or overlay using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, jsp

So here I want to call a child.jsp as a model using JavaScript. Previously I accessed the child jsp as `showmodaldialog and window.open()` using JavaScript. It works, but it is opening in another window. I want the child jsp in modal or overlay view.  Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

When function `showModDilog()` is called, the child jsp should be in modal view or in overlay view with the updated values.

In other hand, I can also use this `(<%@include file="child.jsp" %>`) inside the body to include. But the values which I have passed, is not getting updated in child.jsp.

*If you need more info about this, please feel free to comment. I really appreciate your help.

```
//function to call child.jsp from Parent.jsp
function showModDilog(retVal,curVal,curRow,varPreVal)
    {
        var varRetVal = retVal;
        var varCurrentValue = curVal;
        var varCurrentRow = curRow;
        var varPreValue = varPreVal;
        qsUrl ="../FOLDER/ContentShowModalDialog.do?title="+"ORDER NO - "+varRetVal+" ALREADY EXISTS &varCurrentValue="+varCurrentValue+"&varCurrentRow="+varCurrentRow+"&varPreValue="+varPreValue;
        if(navigator.appName =='Microsoft Internet Explorer')
        {
            event.keyCode=0;
        }   
        else
        {
            event.which=0;
        }   
        event.returnValue=0;
        if(getBrowser()=='IE')
        {
            var qsheight ='200';
            var args = new Object;
            args.window = window;
            returnval = showModalDialog(qsUrl, args);
        }
        else
        {
            var args = new Object;
            args.window = window.opener;
            returnval = window.open(qsUrl, args);
        }
    }
```

.css  used inside child jsp

```
.windowModal {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.windowModal:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

HTML used inside child jsp

```
 <body class="windowModal" bgcolor="#FFCC99">
    <div class=" close" style="width: 100%;overflow: auto;height: 100%;background-color: #F0E68C;">

        <div  style="margin-top: 1%;">
        <input type="button" class="close" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();" >
        <label class="labelbold" style="font-weight: bold; float:left;">NAME - &nbsp; </label>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your css and html working for the styling of the overlay, you can make an ajax request to get the page data and then put it in your parent page.

With pure JavaScript, you can load the child page and then put the contents of the response inside a container in your parent jsp:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("idOfContainerInsideParent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", qsUrl, true);
xhttp.send();
```